# Unknown Runtime Error in delphi7, 'Invalid floating point operation.' No crash

Tags: delphi, runtime-error, delphi-7, pascal

Good day, I need advice on a piece of code I wrote. It is an activity from my delphi7 school textbook, so you can imagine I am still new to pascal. 
My program works fine and gets the results I need, but I receive a strange:
" Invalid floating point operation" message in runtime without the program crashing. With my limited knowledge, I can't find the reason behind this error. It is confusing as I did not use any real numbers but please have a look.
Let me know if you need additional information
Thank you in advance, I am open to learning!

> ```
>    private
>     arrLearners : array of string;
>     arrMod : array of string;
> ```

```
procedure TfrmPortfolios.btnEnterClick(Sender: TObject);
var
numL,k,d,a : integer;
l :string;
begin
  k:=0;
  numL:=0;

  repeat
   numL := StrToInt(InputBox('Enter names','How many learners in Subject?
   (Max 30):','30'));
   until
   numL<=30;
 SetLength(arrLearners, numL);

 for k:=0 to numL-1 do
   begin
        arrLearners[k]:='Student No'+IntToStr(k+1);
   end;

 k:=0;
 d := numL div 5; //used to see for every which learner will go to moderation. I.e if d=3 then every third student.
 if numL <=9 then // below 9, d=1 then it's every student anyways
    begin
         for k:=0 to NumL-1 do
            begin
                 SetLength(arrMod,NumL);
                 arrMod[k]:=arrLearners[k];
            end;
    end
    else
      begin
           a := numL div d;
           SetLength(arrMod, a);
           for k:=0 to a-1 do
               begin

                    arrMod[k] := arrLearners[(k*d) +1];
               end;
       end;

 k:=0;
 redOutput.Lines.Add('Students sent for moderation:'+#13);
 for k:=0 to numL-1 do
   begin
        l:= arrMod[k];
        redOutput.Lines.Add(l);
   end;

end;
```

Comment: I noticed my results were wrong, but I fixed it with and I still get float error:          arrMod[k] := arrLearners[(k*d)+d-1 ];

Comment: If you're running from the Delphi 7 IDE, did it pop you into a particular place in your code after the message? None of the code you show as any explicit floating point values or operations, so the problem is likely somewhere else.

Comment: FWIW, there are a few useful links that show people how to debug. Here is one: [Delphi debugging for dummies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amZIKVk7_-U) , here is another one: [Debug faster, Debug smarter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eqs27gB7Zms) both from different CodeRage events.

Comment: Note that when `numL` is higher than `9`, `arrMod` size is `numL div d`. (that is `numL div 5`). So it's less than `numL`. However, in the last lines you're looking up the values of arrMod from 0..numL-1 - so you're trying to access members higher than the actual size of the array. That can lead to unexpected behavior ("out of bounds" issue)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled range checking and overflow checking options. You can enable them either globally or locally in the code using compiler directives {$R+,O+} Range check is a very useful thing - it can save you much time on debug weird issues.